# breakpoint on initial load - chrome://inspect - webview

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I try to debug a phonegap app using chrome://inspect#devices.

My problem is an error that occurs on the initial loading of angular. So when I load the app on the device, a new webview opens, and when I click 'inspect' the error happened already and it seems like breakpoints are ignored. I cant get breadpoints to work on this initial setup.

Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

and if you keep open dev tool, and use "break on exception"?
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions

Or you can put "debugger;" in js code to install breakpoints programatically.

I'm nit familiar with angular, but knockout have an ovn plugin tool for chrome to debag and I think angular have too.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj

Comment: I tried "debugger;", that didnt work. The option "break on exception" has no effect too. I have the angular chrome plugin installed, but its kind of useless here